# How to install Java application in windows mobile?

Tags: java, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have one problem present i am unble to resolve this one.

Q:How to use java based application in windows mobile?

What are the requirements for java application install in windows mobile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of all, you need a java runtime environment. Check out this thread:

http://www.4winmobile.com/forums/phone-edition-general/15806-jre-windows-mobile-6-a.html

Comment: Sorry ammoQ, i didn't find any solution to my problem.